# How does doc_values work in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Can someone explain to me how does doc_values work?
Why would that help me when doing aggregations?

Would it help me when filtering?

For filtering, the way I see it, ElasticSearch would access the inverted index to find "pointers" to all the documents that fit the aggregations, so doc_values, which is an "uninverted index" according to the documentation, is irrelevant? Or am I wrong?

Can someone explain the flow of an aggregation when doc_values is enabled, and when it isn't, and why enabling it saves memory?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you see it helps filtering ? doc_values will help sorting aggregation and may be script filters ( But not others )

Comment: Your question is answered here:
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html][1]

Comment: @Duc.Duong I read this, of course. It does not explain what I asked. Just that using it will save memory, not why.

I'm looking for a detailed explanation for the difference between the two processes with an without setting doc_values.

Comment: If you feel like watching some Lucene surgery, this won't answer it all but here is a [technical presentation](http://fr.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/willnauer-simon-doc-values-column-stride-fields-in-lucene) (quite old but still accurate) of how they decided to go for doc_values in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

General statements about `doc_values`:

- `doc_values` will help with **heap** memory usage
- they are used for the memory section called `fielddata`
- `fielddata` is being used when sorting, doing aggregations, when using scripts that access field values, when using parent-child relationships and geo-distance filters

Until `doc_values` came into play, fielddata was being loaded into **heap**. `doc_values` will not use the heap, but the memory outside the heap - the file system cache, because `doc_values` will live in the file system. Lucene will access the file system, the operating system will cache it in the file system cache and then serve requests from there.

Why is this important: the heap has a limited size and the recommendation is not to use more than 30ish GB for heap size. The heap, also, contains other sections: filter caches, query caches, indexing buffers, meta-data from the segment files etc. Fielddata, usually, takes a lot of room not because it is inefficient, but because ES needs to load all the documents into memory so that it can sort, aggregate on them. For larger indices (implicitly, shards) this means a lot of data.

That's why `doc_values` were introduced: move all this burden from the heap (which is limited) to the OS file system cache (which is limited, as well, but definitely with less pressure on it).

`doc_values` it will not help you with aggregations per se. `doc_values` means fielddata. **Fielddata is mandatory for aggregations**. `doc_values` will help you with **heap** memory usage.

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed explanation.
So, if I aggregate a "terms" or "cardinality" aggregation, it will still load all of the `fielddata` to the heap? Even if I used `doc_values`?

Comment: If you use doc_values, the values are loaded in memory, but not in heap.

Comment: Does this mean that the fielddata will be loaded into memory in a piecewise manner,  this instead of loading all the fielddata info the heap? Or will it still be loaded fully,  just not in the heap, which is shared with filter caches etc,  but in the remaining machine memory?