# What is the use of doc_values:true in Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elastic search , for mapping they are using

doc_values : true , what is the use of this?

If already asked, Please don't ignore.I need the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does doc\_values work in ElasticSearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354006/how-does-doc-values-work-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html):

> Doc values are now only about 10–25% slower than in-memory fielddata,
>   and come with two major advantages:
>
> - They live on disk instead of in heap memory. This allows you to work with quantities of fielddata that would normally be too large to fit
>     into memory. In fact, your heap space ($ES_HEAP_SIZE) can now be set
>     to a smaller size, which improves the speed of garbage collection and,
>     consequently, node stability.
> - Doc values are built at index time, not at search time. While in-memory fielddata has to be built on the fly at search time by
>     uninverting the inverted index, doc values are prebuilt and much
>     faster to initialize.